# How to get access to settings in `web.xml` during the start of a Spring web application?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have several database connection settings in the `web.xml` file of my application.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>databaseName</param-name>
    <param-value>myDatabase</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>databaseUser</param-name>
    <param-value>myUser</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In a `@PostConstruct` method of a singleton bean, I need to access the values of these settings.

How can I do this?